# Simple Bus event_subscriber services not found in Symfony 4.2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have updated my app from 3.4 to Symfony 4.2 and I'm using [simple-bus/symfony-bridge](http://docs.simplebus.io/en/latest/) v5.2.1 for synchronous and asynchronous events.

In my `services.yaml` I have multiple services tagged as `event_subscriber` which subscribes_to different events.

The issues is that any of the services tagged `event_subscriber` are not found by the service container.

What could cause this issue ? Is this related to Simple Bus bundle or with Symfony framework ?

Comment: You can debug the container using the `debug:container` command. We can’t help you without seeing your container configuration. Anyway, no need for cra**y libraries - Symfony has its own [messenger](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html) now and it rocks.

Comment: I found the issue. I was passing the wrong parameters to RegisterSubscribers in kernel.php

Comment: Imagine no need for declaring a service at all to have a command handler, command as interfaces, handler as interface and all. Messenger is much better.